# Import maven project into Eclipse/Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, export

I downloaded the Megamatcher Android SDK from http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher.html
I already implementend a face identifier on android devices 
now i want compare the performance of my identifier with a corporate one (the one above)
My problem is to export the mvn project from Megamatcher tutorial into an android project under Eclipse.

there's a way to create an eclipse project from a maven one? including all remote and local dependencies??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just this what you are looking for
From: [source](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html):

> If you have a simple java project which is made up of only one module,
>   using eclipse is very simple. To generate the eclipse project files
>   from your POM you execute the following command:
>
> mvn eclipse:eclipse
>
> If you have created or checked out the project with eclipse, you only
>   have to refresh the project in your workspace. Otherwise you have to
>   import the project into your eclipse workspace (From the menu bar,
>   select File >Import >Existing Projects into Workspace). In the latter
>   case the project (directory) should not be located in your workspace,
>   because eclipse might come into trouble, especially if you want to use
>   eclipse as the scm client.